# SAPUI5: How to realize a Menu with the help of MultiComboBox

Tags: javascript, xml, model-view-controller, combobox, sapui5

I muss realize the following Menu:
[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g93f.png)

I decide for this Menu to use: `MultiComboBox`:

```
<MultiComboBox items="{modelExample>/}" >  //Model with a Title and Options
    <core:Item text="{modelExample>option}"/>
</MultiComboBox>
```

**Issues**

1. The Code does showcase all the Options, don't know yet how to place the Title above the Options to achieve this display.
   What i tried: [Link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.MultiComboBox/sample/sap.m.sample.MultiComboBoxGrouping)- doesn't really work
2. How to add a new Column for the MultiComboBox.
3. If i want to add a new ListItem with the help of controller, it looks as this :

   `var l =  new sap.ui.core.ListItem("ID");
   var label = new sap.m.Label();
   label.setText("Hallo Welt");
   l.addCell(label); //Cell isn't supported -> those Error
   MultiComboBox.addItem(l);`
4. `Cell` isn't supported by MultiComboBox unlike Table. -> How can i add a cell/w/e with a title and all the other Options to the ListItem -> than MultiComboBox.addItem(l) ?

**EDIT:**
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSkRY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Tile" is the sorter or better the "group"

```
<MultiComboBox
    selectionChange="handleSelectionChange"
    selectionFinish="handleSelectionFinish"
    width="500px"
    items="{
        path: '/ProductCollection',
        sorter: {
            path: 'SupplierName',
            descending: false,
            group: true
        },
        groupHeaderFactory: '.getGroupHeader'
    }">
    <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" />
</MultiComboBox>
```

For example.. it group ALL Products with the same SupplierName in the combobox.
I dont know how your model looks but extend it with a group and use it on the sorter

and in your controller you need also to mention the function

```
getGroupHeader: function (oGroup) {
        return new SeparatorItem( {
            text: oGroup.key
        });
    }
```

for example your model:

```
{
    "ProductCollection": [
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1000",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "1",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.2,
            "WeightUnit": "KG",
            "Description": "Notebook Basic 15 with 2,80 GHz quad core, 15\" LCD, 4 GB DDR3 RAM, 500 GB Hard Disc, Windows 8 Pro",
            "Name": "Notebook Basic 15",
            "DateOfSale": "2017-03-26",
            "ProductPicUrl": "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/documentation/sdk/images/HT-1000.jpg",
            "Status": "Available",
            "Quantity": 10,
            "UoM": "PC",
            "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
            "Price": 956,
            "Width": 30,
            "Depth": 18,
            "Height": 3,
            "DimUnit": "cm"
        },
        {
            "ProductId": "HT-1001",
            "Category": "Laptops",
            "MainCategory": "Computer Systems",
            "TaxTarifCode": "1",
            "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens",
            "WeightMeasure": 4.5,
            "WeightUnit": "KG",
            "Description": "Notebook Basic 17 with 2,80 GHz quad core, 17\" LCD, 4 GB DDR3 RAM, 500 GB Hard Disc, Windows 8 Pro",
            "Name": "Notebook Basic 17",
            "DateOfSale": "2017-04-17",
            "ProductPicUrl": "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/documentation/sdk/images/HT-1001.jpg",
            "Status": "Available",
            "Quantity": 20,
            "UoM": "PC",
            "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
            "Price": 1249,
            "Width": 29,
            "Depth": 17,
            "Height": 3.1,
            "DimUnit": "cm"
        },
```

you see "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens"

so if you got 10 items with "SupplierName": "Very Best Screens" it will group under Very Best Screens. If you got 1000 items under "tile1" you have Tile 1

Comment: Hey, thank your for you contribution! I already tried out what you did write, i converted `items="{modelExample>/}"` in `items="{path: 'modelExample>/', sorter:{group:true}}"` doesn*t really work

Comment: you need also give the ```path``` in the ```sorter```. The sorter also needs to know WHICH binding path to use for the sorting. Thats why it does not work 

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Sorter%23constructor

Comment: Ok, thank you!! But how does it go about it ? sorter with group -> groups all the Options together and after that it goes to the next item? Also don't understand, by items you use the path option -> for all the items of your model incl title + options, for sorter -> path, only the options?

Comment: probably you should download the example you mentioned.. but i edit my answer

Comment: It has nothing to do with your items (just for the sort). And yes it groups all items togehter. With ``` <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" />``` you just pick the Name in your combobox nothing else of the item

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! It is now understandable but the thing is i do have a quite different model, i don't really have an overarching "ProductCollection" my Model looks a bit different, check the Edit.

Comment: i would change the model like in the example upper.. i dont know if it works with yours.. i make no sense than to use the combobox from ui5

Comment: Ok, well than i guess it can only be done with the controller. In the sap.m.Table, you could add `label` to `cells` then add `cells`  to ColumnListItem(); and as a result add the ColumnListItem to the Table. The Issue: MultiComboBox, doesn't support cells, do you know what will be the equivalent for that?

Comment: but sap.m.Table is not a Combobox.. you can look  here there is no cell aggregation oder smthing else https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MultiComboBox%23methods/Summary